# Namespaces for functions of a ruby class?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to add namespaces into a ruby class? Something like this:

```
my_obj = A.new
my_obj.namespace1.func1(123)
my_obj.namespace1.func22(:aaa)

my_obj.namespace2.func1(456) # different function
my_obj.namespace2.func22("fdsafds") # different function
```

Comment: You can create a contextual object or proxy if you want, but what purpose does that serve?

Comment: namespacing is done using ruby modules, MyModule::AnotherModule::MyClass.new

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. Why do you want to do that and what do you try to achieve? Why can't you use modules that are usually used in Ruby to create namespaces?

Comment: @spickermann it just sounds as such.